# The following ProviderNotFoundException was thrown building Consumer<ApplicationStateLogin>(dirty):

Tags: flutter

The app works when I run it. When I click the icon it displays the LogInFlow widget but in testing it doesn't assert that it found one widget with a Key('LogInFlow').

══╡ EXCEPTION CAUGHT BY WIDGETS LIBRARY ╞═══════════════════════════════════════════════
The following ProviderNotFoundException was thrown building Consumer(dirty):
Error: Could not find the correct Provider above this
Consumer Widget

This happens because you used a `BuildContext` that does not include the provider
of your choice. There are a few common scenarios:

- You added a new provider in your `main.dart` and performed a hot-reload.
  To fix, perform a hot-restart.
- The provider you are trying to read is in a different route.

  Providers are "scoped". So if you insert of provider inside a route, then
  other routes will not be able to access that provider.
- You used a `BuildContext` that is an ancestor of the provider you are trying to read.

  Make sure that Consumer is under your
  MultiProvider/Provider.
  This usually happens when you are creating a provider and trying to read it immediately.

The relevant error-causing widget was:
Consumer
file:///C:/Users/calvo/Documents/flutter/projects/freegapp/lib/main.dart:48:5

══╡ EXCEPTION CAUGHT BY FLUTTER TEST FRAMEWORK ╞════════════════════════════════════════════════════
The following TestFailure object was thrown running a test:
Expected: exactly one matching node in the widget tree
Actual: _KeyFinder:<zero widgets with key [<'LogInFlow'>] (ignoring offstage widgets)>
Which: means none were found but one was expected

When the exception was thrown, this was the stack:
#4      main. (file:///C:/Users/calvo/Documents/flutter/projects/freegapp/test/main_widget_test.dart:25:5)


(elided one frame from package:stack_trace)
...

This was caught by the test expectation on the following line:
file:///C:/Users/calvo/Documents/flutter/projects/freegapp/test/main_widget_test.dart line 25
The test description was:
MyStatefulWidget creates a default widget as a homepage

══╡ EXCEPTION CAUGHT BY FLUTTER TEST FRAMEWORK ╞════════════════════════════════════════════════════
The following message was thrown:
Multiple exceptions (2) were detected during the running of the current test, and at least one was
unexpected.

**
main_widget_test.dart
**

```
// The goal of a widget test is to verify that every widget’s UI looks and behaves as expected.//
// To perform an interaction with a widget in your test, use the WidgetTester
// utility that Flutter provides. For example, you can send tap and scroll
// gestures. You can also use WidgetTester to find child widgets in the widget
// tree, read text, and verify that the values of widget properties are correct.

import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter_test/flutter_test.dart';

import 'package:freegapp/main.dart';

void main() {
  // The WidgetTester allows building and interacting with widgets in a test environment.
  testWidgets('MyStatefulWidget creates a default widget as a homepage',
      (WidgetTester tester) async {
    // Create the widget by telling the tester to build it. Also triggers a frame.
    await tester.pumpWidget(MyApp());
    expect(find.byKey(Key('default')), findsOneWidget);
    // navigationIndexBar starts at 0 so TheMap should be the widget being displayed.
    expect(find.byKey(Key('TheMap')), findsOneWidget);
    // tap on navigationIndexBar 1
    await tester.tap(find.text('icon'));
    // Rebuild the widget after the state has changed.
    await tester.pump();
    expect(find.byKey(Key('LogInFlow')), findsOneWidget);
    await tester.tap(find.text('Map'));
    await tester.pump();
    expect(find.byKey(Key('TheMap')), findsOneWidget);
  });
}
```

**
main.dart
**

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter_config/flutter_config.dart';
import 'package:provider/provider.dart';
import 'src/ApplicationStateLogin.dart';
import 'package:freegapp/TheMap.dart';
import 'package:freegapp/src/ApplicationStateLogin.dart';
import 'package:freegapp/src/LogInFlow.dart';

void main() async {
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized(); // Required by FlutterConfig
  await FlutterConfig.loadEnvVariables();

  runApp(
    ChangeNotifierProvider(
      create: (context) => ApplicationStateLogin(),
      builder: (context, _) => MyApp(),
    ),
  );
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  // This widget is the root of your application.
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Freegap',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
      ),
      home: MyStatefulWidget(key: Key('default')),
    );
  }
}

class MyStatefulWidget extends StatefulWidget {
  MyStatefulWidget({Key? key})
      : super(key: key); // Initializes key for subclasses.
  @override
  _MyStatefulWidgetState createState() => _MyStatefulWidgetState();
}

class _MyStatefulWidgetState extends State<MyStatefulWidget> {
  // for bottom navigation bar
  int _selectedIndex = 0;
  // Widget array for bottom navigation bar
  static final List<Widget> _widgetOptions = <Widget>[
    TheMap(key: Key('TheMap')),
    Consumer<ApplicationStateLogin>(
      builder: (context, appState, _) => LogInFlow(
          email: appState.email,
          loginState: appState.loginState,
          startLoginFlow: appState.startLoginFlow,
          verifyEmail: appState.verifyEmail,
          signInWithEmailAndPassword: appState.signInWithEmailAndPassword,
          cancelRegistration: appState.cancelRegistration,
          registerAccount: appState.registerAccount,
          signOut: appState.signOut,
          key: Key('LogInFlow')),
    ),
  ];
  // for bottom navigation bar
  void _onItemTapped(int index) {
    setState(() {
      _selectedIndex = index;
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Center(
        child: _widgetOptions.elementAt(_selectedIndex),
      ),
      // body:
      bottomNavigationBar: BottomNavigationBar(
        items: const <BottomNavigationBarItem>[
          BottomNavigationBarItem(
            icon: Icon(Icons.map_outlined),
            label: 'Map',
          ),
          BottomNavigationBarItem(
            icon: Icon(Icons.home_outlined),
            label: 'icon',
          ),
        ],
        currentIndex: _selectedIndex,
        onTap: _onItemTapped,
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured it out. I was building the wrong widget in the test file. I need to build the ChangeNotifierProvider widget and provide the appropriate packages.

```
    await tester.pumpWidget(ChangeNotifierProvider(
      create: (context) => ApplicationStateFirebase(),
      builder: (context, _) => MyApp(),
    ));
```

instead of

```
await tester.pumpWidget(MyApp());
```